# When can one use only the particular solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I have the following PDE

$$xu_x+u_y-(y+z)u_z=0$$

So I have to solve $$\frac{dx}{dt}=x,\frac{dy}{dt}=1,\frac{dz}{dt}=-(y+z),\frac{du}{dt}=0$$

I got $$x(t,s_1,s_2)=e^t\cdot f_1(s_1,s_2)$$ $$y(t,s_1,s_2)=t+f_2(s_1,s_2)$$

So for $\frac{dz}{dt}=-(y+z)$ I have to solve:
$$z'+z=-t-f_2(s_1,s_2)$$

So

$z=z_h+z_p$

$$z'_h+z_h=0\rightarrow z_h=c\cdot e^{-t}$$

now $z_p=c(t,s_1,s_2)\cdot e^{-t}$

we derive and plug it back to the ODE $z'+z=-t-f_2(s_1,s_2)$
:

$$-c(t,s_1,s_2)\cdot e^{-t}+c'(t,s_1,s_2)\cdot e^{-t}+c(t,s_1,s_2)\cdot e^{-t}=-t-f_2(s_1,s2)$$

$$c'(t,s_1,s_2)\cdot e^{-t}=-t-f_2(s_1,s2)\Rightarrow c(t,s_1,s_2)=-te^{t}+e^{t}-f_2(s_1,s_2)e^{t}+f_3(s_1,s_2)$$

So $$z_p=(te^{t}+e^{t}-f_2(s_1,s_2)e^{t}+f_3(t,s_1,s_2))e^{-t}=t+1-f_2(s_1,s_2)+f_3(s_1,s_2)e^{-t}$$

So the solution is:

$$z=z_h+z_p=c\cdot e^{-t}+(te^{t}+e^{t}-f_2(s_1,s_2)e^{t}+f_3(t,s_1,s_2))e^{-t}=t+1-f_2(s_1,s_2)+f_3(s_1,s_2)e^{-t}$$

Now from what I know $z=z_h+z_p$ where $z_h$ is the solution of the homogeneous system and $z_p$ is the particular solution.

But in the end of the exercise it seems that the solution is only $z_p$

$$z=(t+1)+f_1(s_1,s_2)+e^t\cdot f_3(s_1,s_2)$$

What is correct?

Comment: What is $s_1, s_2$? What is written in the end of the exercise? You have to provide more context.

Comment: @Jan it was a part of a PDE, so I thought it will be better to ask on the specific part that I did not understand, added more info, sorry

Comment: No problem, looks good now. Could you give a reference for the exercise and especially the solution which you give at the end? From which source is it?

Comment: @newhere. The PDE is considered as solved (totally or partly) when at least a relationship between $u,x,y,z$ has been found. I don't see $u$ in your "solution".

Comment: @Jan it is an handwritten solution in another language

Comment: @JJacquelin I stopped after the solution of the 2 ODE, I do not understand why in the solution they only take the particular solution and not both particular and homogeneous one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have correctly written
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=x,\frac{dy}{dt}=1,\frac{dz}{dt}=-(y+z),\frac{du}{dt}=0$$
Or equivalently on the form of the Charpit-Lagrange system : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics
$$\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dy}{1}=\frac{dz}{-(y+z)}=\frac{du}{0}=dt$$
A first characteristic equation comes from $\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dy}{1}$ . Solving leads to :
$$xe^{-y}=c_1$$
A second characteristic equation comes from $\frac{dy}{1}=\frac{dz}{-(y+z)}$ . Solving $\frac{dz}{dy}+z+y=0$ leads to  :
$$(y+z-1)e^y=c_2$$
A third characteristic equation comes from necessarily $du=0$ :
$$u=c_3$$
The general solution of the PDE expressed on the form of implicit equation is :
$$\Phi(c_1,c_2,c_3)=\Phi\big(xe^{-y}\:,\:(y+z-1)e^y\:,\:u\big)=0$$
where $\Phi$ is an arbitrary function of three variables.

Or equivalently 
$$\boxed{u(x,y,z)=F\big(xe^{-y}\:,\:(y+z-1)e^y\big)}$$
where $F$ is an arbitrary function of two variables.

It is easy to check that this equation satisfies the PDE with the calculus of $u_x$ , $u_y$ , $u_z$ and putting them into the PDE.

This shows that they are an infinity of solutions until some boundary condition be specified in order to determine the function $F$.

NOTE: Among the general solution found above, some less general solutions are $u=f(xe^{-y})$ and $u=g\big((y+z-1)e^y\big)$ where $f$ and $g$ are arbitrary functions.